# How to assign a generic object to non generic reference in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I am a Java guy, and trying to implement some code in C#. I did a research for an hour but couldn't find any. 
I have an interface that I declared as Generic called

```
interface TypeSerializer<T>
```

Then I have two implementation of this.

```
class StringSerializer: TypeSerializer<String>
```

and

```
class ByteArraySerializer: TypeSerializer<byte[]>
```

Now I want to create an array with these instances and refer to array as TypeSerializer. Sth like this:

```
TypeSerializer[] serializers = 
new TypeSerializer[2] {new ByteArraySerializer(), new StringSerializer()};
```

This code doesn't compile, however in Java a similar code does compile.

I also tried sth

```
TypeSerializer<Object>[] serializers = 
new TypeSerializer<Object>[2] {new ByteArraySerializer(), new StringSerializer()};
```

still no way.

How should I declare this array and reach to the instances without knowing the Generic Type.

***EDIT***

Based on the answers below it becomes clear that I should have two interfaces; with and without generic. 
Here is the Interface methods. Could you please show also how to implement them.

```
public interface ITypeSerializer<T>:TypeSerializer
{
    void write(BinaryWriter writer, T obj);
    T read(BinaryReader reader);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the bright world of C# ;-)

Comment: @Steven Thanks, having some trouble to find out my way in this bright world:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a non-generic version of the interface that the generic version inherits, which forces the implementations to the classes as usual.

```
interface ITypeSerializer { }
interface ITypeSerializer<T> : ITypeSerializer { }
class StringSerializer : ITypeSerializer<string> { } // implements ITypeSerializer, too 

// non-generic array
ITypeSerializer[] serializers = ...
```

Any method that you need on `ITypeSerializer` should either accept or return `object`, with the implementations typically being pass-through methods for the generic versions.

An implementation example:

```
public interface ITypeSerializer
{
    void Write(BinaryWriter writer, object obj);
    object Read(BinaryReader reader);
}

public interface ITypeSerializer<T> : ITypeSerializer
{
    void Write(BinaryWriter writer, T obj); 
    T Read(BinaryReader reader);
}
```

When you implement `ITypeSerializer<T>`, you also need to provide implementations for the `ITypeSerializer` methods. A common pattern is to implement the generic implicitly and the non-generic explicitly, so that the non-generic methods are only visible when referring to the class via the interface.

```
class StringSerializer : ITypeSerializer<string>
{
    // implicit implementation of ITypeSerializer<string>
    public void Write(BinaryWriter writer, string obj)
    {
        // provide core implementation here
    }

    public string Read(BinaryReader reader)
    {
        // provide core implementation here
    }

    // explicit implementation of ITypeSerializer
    void ITypeSerializer.Write(BinaryWriter writer, object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is string)) throw new ArgumentException("obj");

        this.Write(writer, (string)obj);
    }

    object ITypeSerializer.Read(BinaryReader reader)
    {
        return this.Read(reader);
    }
}
```

Notice how the non-generic methods are simply passing to/from the generic counterparts.

Comment: Can you also show how to implement it I updated the question. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your interface can be declared like this:

```
interface TypeSerializer<out T>
```

the "out" makes your uses the generic variance feature of C#, and you'll be able to compile the second form you tried:

```
TypeSerializer<Object>[] serializers = 
new TypeSerializer<Object>[2] {new ByteArraySerializer(), new StringSerializer()};
```

This will work in C# 4.0 and later

Comment: I am using Mono, so this didn't work? <out T> didn't compile. Is there any namespace I should be using?

Comment: Hmm, not sure about that one.  I think Mono has some support for C# 4.0 features, but can't say specifically if it has this one.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't going to know the generic type, it isn't ideal to use a generic interface. I would be tempted to use:

```
interface ITypeSerializer {...}
```

with an API that works with `object`. In most cases, this will not present an issue - as you are most likely serializing classes (so no boxing). The occasional cast is *not* going to be an issue.

If you really want, you can have a dual generic/non-generic API, but unless you need it that is probably overkill (says someone who has spent a ***lot*** of time working with pretty-much this exact scenario).

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
interface ITypeSerializer { }
interface ITypeSerializer<T> : ITypeSerializer { }
```

Note that it's C# convention to name interfaces starting with a capital `I`